# Svnadmin load from dumpfile causes "file not found error". Help?

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin

> Given:
>
> Repository_1 - source
>
> Repository_2 - destination

I created a dump file of Repository_1/Folder1 using combination of svnadmin and svndumpfilter

When loading from the dump file from **Repository_1/Folder1** into **Repository_2/Trunk** everything is fine **BUT**

When loading from **Repository_1/Folder1/Sub-folder**(created another dump for this) into **Repository_2/trunk** i get the following error:

```
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '267-89', path 'trunk/Folder1/Sub-folder'
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Turns out that structure(empty folders) in destination needs to pre-created.
So,
If you want to do this:

When loading from **Repository_1/Folder1/Sub-folder**(created another dump for this) into **Repository_2/trunk**

> you need to created this structure in
>   svn
>
> **Repository_2/trunk/Folder1**

note: you only need to create parents, not the folder itself, so DO NOT CREATE **Repository_2/trunk/Folder1/Sub-folder**

Comment: It solves my problem. Thanks a ton. Could you look into this problem.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238863/include-multiple-folders-using-svndumpfilter

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/subversion_users/kSU8jIX3m-Q/y3DveKoeRbsJ), `svnrdump` works differently from `svndump`.

`svndump` + `svndumpfilter`:

- Dumps the entire repository history, then filters for the things you want. This takes a long time on large repositories, even if you're just grabbing a tiny subtree.
- Produces a dumpfile that is probably broken in a number of ways, like creating files in directories that don't exist or copying files from paths that don't exist.

`svnrdump`:

- Produces a self-consistent dumpfile.
- Requires a subpath if you want to do the equivalent of `svndumpfilter include`. For example, `svnrdump https://server.example.com/svn/repo/branches/1.4` would grab all the revisions affecting /branches/1.4.
- May require an additional `| svndumpfilter include / --drop-all-empty-revs --renumber-revs`.

Bottom line: `svnrdump` will probably work better.

Answer (score 1):

you'll get this error if someone copied something from trunk/Folder1 to trunk/Folder1/Sub-folder. since you have only included trunk/Folder1/Sub-folder in your dump, it cannot find the required file(s) from trunk/Folder1 anymore and stops with this error.

to solve this you'll have to make sure to include everything in the dump that has been the source of a copy.

Answer (score 1):

I have just experienced this error which I traced to a recent server upgrade and a `svnadmin dump/load` cycle.  The problem was that I had set up the repository in a different directory to the one it was created in.

On the old machine, I was using `inetd.conf` to run `svnserve`:

```
svnserve -r /var/svn/main
```

and the repository was in /var/svn/main

However on the new machine I had `inetd.conf` pointing to `/var/svn`:

```
svnserve -r /var/svn
```

I already had a checkout from the old server, so when I tried to commit the destination path didn't exist because I'd accidentally added another component to the URL, so `svn://host/source/trunk` became `svn://host/main/source/trunk`.

I could have fixed it by moving the directories around, but I chose instead to rewrite the URL of the working copy using `svn switch --relocate`.

Note: a quick diagnostic to see whether this is the problem is to change to a directory in your working copy, type `svn info` to get the repository URL and then type `svn ls <myUrl>`.  If this gives a `No repository found` error then you know this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the dump fails because `trunk/Folder1` creation was filtered by svndumpfilter. According to [this blog post](https://blog.tinned-software.net/splitting-up-an-svn-repository/), these steps are needed on the dump :

You can create trunk/Folder1 in the dump, by editing the dump itself and add to the first revision the following block:

```
Node-path: trunk/Folder1
Node-action: add
Node-kind: dir
Prop-content-length: 10
Content-length: 10
PROPS-END
```

This block must be inserted in the props blocks of the first revision.

Then the dump can be loaded with svnadmin.