# SVN move sub folder to another repository

Tags: svn

We are in process of moving a legacy Java project to a gradle based project.
For which I want to move just the java and jsp folder from following path

`svn
└───Dev
    └───ReleaseBuilds
        └───V10
            └───10e186
                ├───java
                ├───jsp
                └───migration`

to java and jsp in following path in the same svn server on different repository.

`svn
10e
├───branches
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           ├───java
│           └───webapps
│               └───jsp
└───trunk`

There are multiple questions on similar lines like the following but for this specif case my new repository ends up mirroring the whole folder structure from the legacy repo when I use the following commands

`svnadmin dump Dev | svndumpfilter include /ReleaseBuilds/V10/10e186/java/ >dev.dump`

`svnadmin load --parent-dir branches/10e186 10e7 < dev.dumpsvnadmin load --parent-dir branches/10e186 10e < dev.dump`

The expected result is to get just the content of java folder from old repo to new repo instead I am ending up with path like

`10e/branches/10e186/ReleaseBuilds/V10/10e186/java`

[How do I dump one project out of an SVN repository which contains multiple projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337024/how-do-i-dump-one-project-out-of-a-svn-repository-which-contains-multiple-projec)

[Svnadmin load from dumpfile causes "file not found error". Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359448/svnadmin-load-from-dumpfile-causes-file-not-found-error-help)

[SVN move single directory into other repository (with history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337470/svn-move-single-directory-into-other-repository-with-history)

[How do I move a single folder from one Subversion repository to another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417726/how-to-move-a-single-folder-from-one-subversion-repository-to-another-repository)